# Call Post method having multiple parameters in cshtml file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api

I have declared a method in my MVC WebApi as:

```
[Route("api/User/LoginUser")]
public string PostLogin(string email, string password, string authkey)
{
//  Do Something
    return "";
}
```

Now in cshtml file for testing purpose i am calling the method as:

```
function LoginUser() {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + "api/User/LoginUser",
            type: "Post",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ email: "xyz@gmail.com", password: "password", authkey: "1234" }),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // Do Soemthing
            },
            fail: function (data) {
                // Failed
            }
        });
    }
```

But the api is never called. I am not getting the problem. Please someone help me, i am stuck bigtime here.

Thanx in advance. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make a little examination. Creating new WebApi Project, then create a `TestController` extending `ApiController`, then make a method with your model in it

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string SomeThing(string name, string age)
    {
        return "smth";
    }
```

Now compile the application and open `localhost/Help`

There's documentation about available method. Our `Test` controller is also documented. Let's see what's there:

```
Test
API Description
POST api/Test?name={name}&age={age} 

No documentation available.
```

It seems that mulitple params are automatically mapped as GET parameters instead extracted from the key/value pairs from the post request body. This is because of the default `HttpParameterBinding` and if you want to change it, you will need to extend it, override some things and tell your app to use your crafted override of `HttpParameterBinding`.

Luckily, there's a blogpost regarding how to create your own Parameter binding ( http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API )

All credits given to the author of the blogpost, I will just paste some of the code, if the link gets broken.

Create a class somewhere in your application that extends `HttpParameterBinding`

```
public class SimplePostVariableParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    private const string MultipleBodyParameters = "MultipleBodyParameters";

    public SimplePostVariableParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor)
        : base(descriptor)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check for simple binding parameters in POST data. Bind POST
    /// data as well as query string data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="metadataProvider"></param>
    /// <param name="actionContext"></param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
                                                HttpActionContext actionContext,
                                                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {               
        string stringValue = null;

        NameValueCollection col = TryReadBody(actionContext.Request);
        if (col != null)
            stringValue = col[Descriptor.ParameterName];

        // try reading query string if we have no POST/PUT match
        if (stringValue == null)
        {
            var query = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
            if (query != null)
            {
                var matches = query.Where(kv => kv.Key.ToLower() == Descriptor.ParameterName.ToLower());
                if (matches.Count() > 0)
                    stringValue = matches.First().Value;
            }
        }

        object value = StringToType(stringValue);

        // Set the binding result here
        SetValue(actionContext, value);

        // now, we can return a completed task with no result
        TaskCompletionSource<AsyncVoid> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<AsyncVoid>();
        tcs.SetResult(default(AsyncVoid));
        return tcs.Task;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Method that implements parameter binding hookup to the global configuration object's
    /// ParameterBindingRules collection delegate.
    /// 
    /// This routine filters based on POST/PUT method status and simple parameter
    /// types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.
    ///       .ParameterBindingRules
    ///       .Insert(0,SimplePostVariableParameterBinding.HookupParameterBinding);
    /// </example>    
    /// <param name="descriptor"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static HttpParameterBinding HookupParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        var supportedMethods = descriptor.ActionDescriptor.SupportedHttpMethods;      

        // Only apply this binder on POST and PUT operations
        if (supportedMethods.Contains(HttpMethod.Post) ||
            supportedMethods.Contains(HttpMethod.Put))
        {
            var supportedTypes = new Type[] { typeof(string), 
                                                typeof(int), 
                                                typeof(decimal), 
                                                typeof(double), 
                                                typeof(bool),
                                                typeof(DateTime),
                                                typeof(byte[])
                                            };            

            if (supportedTypes.Where(typ => typ == descriptor.ParameterType).Count() > 0)
                return new SimplePostVariableParameterBinding(descriptor);
        }

        return null;
    }


    private object StringToType(string stringValue)
    {
        object value = null;

        if (stringValue == null)
            value = null;
        else if (Descriptor.ParameterType == typeof(string))
            value = stringValue;
        else if (Descriptor.ParameterType == typeof(int))
            value = int.Parse(stringValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        else if (Descriptor.ParameterType == typeof(Int32))
            value = Int32.Parse(stringValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        else if (Descriptor.ParameterType == typeof(Int64))
            value = Int64.Parse(stringValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        else if (Descriptor.ParameterType == typeof(decimal))
            value = decimal.Parse(stringValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        else if (Descriptor.ParameterType == typeof(double))
            value = double.Parse(stringValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        else if (Descriptor.ParameterType == typeof(DateTime))
            value = DateTime.Parse(stringValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        else if (Descriptor.ParameterType == typeof(bool))
        {
            value = false;
            if (stringValue == "true" || stringValue == "on" || stringValue == "1")
                value = true;
        }
        else
            value = stringValue;

        return value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read and cache the request body
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private NameValueCollection TryReadBody(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
       object result = null;

        // try to read out of cache first
        if (!request.Properties.TryGetValue(MultipleBodyParameters, out result))
        {
            var contentType = request.Content.Headers.ContentType;

            // only read if there's content and it's form data
            if (contentType == null || contentType.MediaType != "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            {
                // Nope no data
                result = null;
            }
            else
            {
                // parsing the string like firstname=Hongmei&lastname=ASDASD            
                result = request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result;
            }

            request.Properties.Add(MultipleBodyParameters, result);            
        }

        return result as NameValueCollection;
    }

    private struct AsyncVoid
    {
    }
}
```

Then in `Startup.cs` invoke the global configuration and insert before all param binding rules, your own rule (on first position in the structure) by invoking the factory method `HookupParameterBinding`

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(
                0, 
                SimplePostVariableParameterBinding.HookupParameterBinding
);
```

Now recompile the application and check again the help page. You controller now does not require you to send the method signature as GET request

```
Test
API Description
POST api/Test   

No documentation available.
```

Now trying our method, like they tried it in the blogpost

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" value="ggg" />
    Age: <input type="text" id="age" value="ddd" />

    <input type="button" id="btnSend" value="Send" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnSend").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:50931/api/Test",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                age: $("#age").val()
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

By clicking the button, we recieve an alert saying `smth`, because we do `return "smth"

If we open the freibug console and track what does we send via jquery, we will see

```
POST http://localhost:50931/api/Test

200 OK
        2ms 
jquery-1.10.2.js (line 8720)
HeadersPostResponseJSONCookies
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencodedDo not sort
age 
ddd
name    
ggg
```

As an alternative we can use a simple json serializing, so we can make our method signature to expect `JObject`

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string SomeThing(JObject obj)
    {
        return obj["name"] + " bla " + obj["age"];
    }
}
```

if we do a POST against this method, like with the HTML above, we recieve alert saying `ddd bla ggg`.

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi I have edited the post giving the example.

Comment: Thanx a lot for the help. Let me check the code again. Will be back in 2 minz

Comment: Oh, one more thing. You are missing `[FromBody]` attribute in the parameters listing.

Comment: Please could you explain [FromBody] attribute

Comment: Yes, but it raises the complexity, first thing I will ask if you will be satisfied if your method instead of 3 params is expecting one param of type Json Object. If not, then we will try to resolve your issue, because I understimated it. If it's ok for you, I will explain how to make your method to expect only `JObject obj` and extract name, pass, authkey as keys

Comment: Yeah for sure why not ??

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi I have explained both ways

Comment: Thanx a tonne for the help.

Comment: @RoyalBg Well done for getting to the bottom of this! +1

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your data as a json object however your action paramters are simple types that it expects to find in the url.
Try creating a complex object for your POST.

```
public class LoginUser
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password{ get; set; }
    public string authkey{ get; set; }
}
```

and change your Api action to

```
[Route("api/User/LoginUser")]
public string PostLogin(LoginUser user)
{
    string email - user.email;
    string password- user.email;
    string authkey- user.email;
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I dont want to create a class for this, thats the only reason i am stuck. Thanx for the help.

Comment: It depends whether you have a choice.  I believe that binding multiple parameters in WebAPI might require a class to bind.